# Conditional Sum in Power BI Matrix

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, powerbi-desktop, business-intelligence

I have a Power BI matrix with 3 columns: 2019, 2020, and 2021. Each row is an item number, and each value is a total quantity produced in the corresponding year column.

I am trying to find a way to display the sum of ONLY items that were blank in 2019 and 2020, BUT have a total quantity in the 2021 column. Is there a way to conditionally format this?

Basically, another way of saying the logic is: total sum of all items where 2019 AND 2020 are blank, AND 2021 is not blank.

Comment: Can you add some input and expected output data?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution if it helps then mark it as the answer.

Create a calculated column with the following DAX:

```
Column =
IF (
    ( 
       Table[Year] = 2019 || Table[Year] = 2020 ),
     IF ( ISBLANK ( Table[Item] ), ( Table[Quant] ) ),
     IF ( Table[Year] = 2021, IF ( ISNUMBER ( Table[Item] ), ( Table[Quant] ) ) )
  )
```

Input I used:-

[image: Input]

Output where 2019 and 2020 Items are blank and 2021 where Items are not blank:-

[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem with this is that in the data table, there aren't blanks for the quantity column. What's happening is, I have 3 different cities within each year, and my matrix is showing each item number's total quantity by year for each city. So blank values in my matrix represent a data point that does not exist in my source table (not a blank value in the source table).

Comment: @c120 Can you please at least add dummy data or input and output values for clarification? You can try to replace `ISBLANK` with `ISTEXT`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the following measure:

```
Measure =
IF (
   CALCULATE(
      SUM(Table[Quantity]),
      Table[Year] => 2019,
      Table[Year] <= 2020,
   ) > 0,
   0,
   CALCULATE(
      SUM(Table[Quantity]),
      Table[Year] = 2021
   )
)
```

And in the table you should filter that visual so it only shows values where this Measure is > 0. However, if your intention is to have this dynamically (i.e. so this still makes sense next year with years 2020, 2021 and 2022), I would recommend this:

```
Measure =
IF (
   CALCULATE(
      SUM(Table[Quantity]),
      Table[Year] => YEAR(TODAY()) - 2,
      Table[Year] <= YEAR(TODAY()) - 1,
   ) > 0,
   0,
   CALCULATE(
      SUM(Table[Quantity]),
      Table[Year] = YEAR(TODAY())
   )
)
```